# Physical USB Keyboard for coding on the Android AIDE app

Tags: keyboard, virtual-keyboard, aide-ide, android-usb, aide

I am running Android 8.1 Oreo on a smartphone device.

I would like to know, can I mount this [KeyTronic USB Keyboard](http://104-key%20Keyboard%20USB%20with%2095%20Key%20&%202port%20USB%20Hub%20https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00006B6NU/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_PaoMCbTWTBH1T) onto my Android phone using a USB to microUSB Adapter?

I want to use it in place the default GBoard soft Keyboard on Android, and use it to code on AIDE.

I don't know if the screen is too small, but I want to try using the keyboard while lying down with a pillow under my head to have me lean up, and the keyboard and smartphone stuck to my upper bent legs. I think this way I can code while lying down and probably don't need a tablet.

Thanks.

Comment: If this question is inappropriate for this site then could you please migrate it to Android SE? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, AIDE (Android IDE) supports USB keyboards, as well as mice (e.g. via Bluetooth). In this way, it is possible to code almost like on a laptop.

AIDE on a 10" tablet enables fairly comfortable work, but have in mind that e.g. on a 5" phone you won't be able to show on the sreen more than 13-15 lines (in landscape mode).

The question, however, is whether YOUR DEVICE supports USB keyboards, which cannot be determined since you mentioned neither the brand nor the model. To answer this, simply refer to the manual of your phone.